# How to enhance Witch Hexes?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, witch

I want to **increase** the **DC** of the hexes my witch uses. Mainly this would be **evil eye** and **deep slumber**. As far as I understand spell focus didn't work because it states that only spells could be enhanced. Are there other possibilities?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I just finished playing a witch in Carrion Crown, and here's how I augmented her hexes ([full character sheet](https://mxyzplk.files.wordpress.com/2013/05/sredni-vashtars-girl-l14.pdf)). I got her Misfortune hex up to DC 27 at level 14.

1. Ability Focus. GM permission required but he was fine with it.
2. INT boosts. In my case, a Headband of Vast Intelligence.
3. [Hexing runes](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/h-l/hexing-runes), boosts one by +1 DC.
4. You have to get it onto your target or get some of their hair, but for high prep combats the [hexing doll](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/h-l/hexing-doll) gives quite a boost. Go root through the wizard's bedroom before killing them and get a hair sample.

Comment: That's a creepy weasel.

Answer (score 3):

The only Feat that I´m aware of is the **Ability Focus** Feat. But since its a Monster Feat it might be considered illegal for your character.

http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/monster-feats/ability-focus

> Benefit: Choose one of the creature's special attacks. Add +2 to the
>   DC for all saving throws against the special attack on which the
>   creature focuses.

The bard cantrip **lullaby** boosts sleep DC's by 2 if they fail that save (and also a -5 perception), and you can take the cantrip with Two World Magic trait.

> Any creature within the area that fails a Will save becomes drowsy and
>   inattentive, taking a -5 penalty on Perception checks and a -2 penalty
>   on Will saves against sleep effects while the lullaby is in effect.
>   Lullaby lasts for as long as the caster concentrates, plus up to 1
>   round per caster level thereafter.

Slumber Hex DC is also affected by the Elven alternate racial trait **Dreamspeaker**.

> Dreamspeaker: A few elves have the ability to tap into the power of
>   sleep, dreams, and prescient reverie. Elves with this racial trait add
>   +1 to the saving throw DCs of spells of the divination school and sleep effects they cast. In addition, elves with Charisma scores of 15
>   or higher may use dream once per day as a spell-like ability (caster
>   level is equal to the elf's character level). This racial trait
>   replaces elven immunities.

Another character creation option to maximize hex DCs is to create a scarred witch Doctor. This class uses Constitution in place of int. As patron you choose water witch patron. This allows you to use elemental body for a +8 bonus to constitution. This will add 4 to your DCs.

Comment: nasty combo on that scarred water witch...

Comment: I'm not sure whether Deamspeaker works. Because it states "spell of the[...]" but it is a hex which is a supernatural ability. Anyway, thanks for the nasty combo :D

Comment: It also states "and sleep effects". Thats the important part :)